# Cannot send data using GKMatch.sendData(toAllPlayers:, with: ) in IOS 14

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit, ios14, gkmatchmaker

I am writing a multiplayer gamein iOS using Gamekit. I am trying to send data from a player to other using below methods

```
match.send(data, to: [player], dataMode: .reliable)
match.sendData(toAllPlayers: data, with: .reliable)
```

It works fine on ios 13 but on ios 14 (Beta 2) and build on Xcode 12.0 (beta 2), I see below message

> [Error] WARNING: -[GKMatch sendData:toPlayers:dataMode:error:] is
> obsoleted. Game Center doesn't invoke this obsoleted method from
> iOS/tvOS 14.0 and macOS 10.16 onwards

I don't see any alternative methods in the documentation. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Neither of these methods are marked as obsolete in iOS 14 SDK. I assume it is a bug, so worth submitting feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you run the app using Xcode version 11.5. I have tried it on two devices running iOS 14 beta 2 and they can send data back and forth.

Apple replied to my feedback request on July 20th and said “the new issue you found has been fixed recently”

Comment: @MithraSingam I have the same problem that you described when I run it on Xcode 12